# How to manage routing with Ant Design Layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

Basically I have a structure as below:

```js
<div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} exact />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <AppAlert />
              <Layout
                style={{
                  minHeight: "100vh",
                }}
              >
                <Sider>
                  <div
                    className={style.logo_wrapper}
                    style={{
                      height: 32,
                      margin: 16,
                    }}
                  >
                    <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
                    <p>Shipping Calculation</p>
                  </div>
                  <SideNav />
                </Sider>
                <Layout className="site-layout">
                  <Content
                    style={{
                      margin: "0 16px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      style={{
                        marginTop: "16px",
                        padding: 24,
                        minHeight: 360,
                      }}
                    >
                      <AppContent /> {*/ HERE IS WHERE I RENDER THE CONTENT */}
                    </div>
                  </Content>
                  <Footer
                    style={{
                      textAlign: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    Shipping Calculation ©2023 Created by Owenn Gimli
                  </Footer>
                </Layout>
              </Layout>
            </>
          }
          exact
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
```

So I have this `<AppContent />` component which changes according to the route and it has code:

```js
<Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} exact />
      <Route path="/kalkulasi-produk" element={<KalkulasiProduk />} exact />
      <Route path="/produk" element={<Produk />} exact />
      <Route path="/supplier" element={<Supplier />} exact />
      <Route path="/lokasi-kargo" element={<LokasiKargo />} exact />
      <Route path="/aktivitas" element={<Aktivitas />} exact />
      <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} exact />
</Routes>
```

I use `<Layout />` from `ant-design` which means I have a sidebar on the left side which is my navigation bar and on the right will be the content of the page. However, I want to add a new page which is a `<LoginPage />` and it shouldn't include the sidebar, so it shouldn't be inside of the `<Layout />` component. How can I modify this? Because currently, if I try to navigate to `/produk`, it will show me a white screen with an error saying that `No routes matched location "/produk"`. How should I structure this?

Extra info that might help: I want to use Firebase authentication to handle authentication in the backend.